# a Python nesting For loop iterating through an ESRI List

Tags: python, for-loop

Sorry to ask such a basic question but:

I've tried repeatedly to iterate through a nested Python loop with no success.  The objective is to peer into each Feature Dataset (about 25 of them) and extract all Feature Classes, then concatenate as such: Buildings / structures_existing_area etc.

This is the best I've done but it doesn't work.

```
import arcpy

gdb = "U:/GeoDatabases/Bragg_MASTER_FileGeoDataBase10.gdb" 
arcpy.env.workspace = gdb

def listFcsInGDB():
    for fds in arcpy.ListDatasets('','feature') + ['']:
        for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('','',fds):
            print (fds +" / "+fc)
```

Thanks in advance.
Stacy

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Because at the moment, you're simply not calling your `ListFcsInGDB()` function, which would indeed lead to nothing.

Comment: Evert, I apologize for not being more explicit however, your comment made me realize my mistake, you answered it!: I didn't need a function to do this, simply eliminating the function line made it work perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: When i commented out the line "def listFcsInGDB():"  and then ran the code block it worked just like I had wanted.  The purpose of this is to determine what blocks of code need to be strung together to iterate through a geodatabase, extract each feature class, and -based on geometry type- run a Conversion to CAD process.  Thanks again Evert.